# Web: What's the correct path to CSS?

Tags: html, css

i have this structure in my project[image: Structure]

I have this page 27.html, so i have to find the CSS file, so i think the correct path was :

```
<link href="../../../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../../css/inner.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

But it's not working, so i wonder why this happens..

Any idea ?

UDPATE:
Hi guys, this is my URL:
/web/blog/2011/june/27.html

I'm trying

```
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

But still not applying the css in the page.

Best regards,
Valter Henrique.

Comment: If the url is /web/blog/... then that absolute path definitely won't work... Best case you'd have to do /web/css/style.css  but that still sorta stinky because what if /web/ changes?

Comment: @Steve, i do what you said, but still not working, i'm develop in netbeans IDE. Could be that ?

Comment: @Valter; If you use FireBug, Chrome Dev Tools, or IE Dev Tools, what HTTP status code are you getting back when the browser tries to download those files? 404 or something else?

Comment: @Steve, one second, i don't use neither. I use google chrome as browser, i will install chrome dev tools.

Comment: @Steve i install firebug, how can i see this error that you meant ?
In console -> errors it don't appers anything about it, just some errors in js.

Comment: @Valter; Activate firebug, then click on the "Net" tab. Then reload your page. http://getfirebug.com/network

Comment: @Steve, i did what you said and don't appears nothing dude.

Comment: @valter: It doesn't show anything for that file, or anything at all? If just for that file, could you post the html surrounding your <link> in your post?

Comment: @Steve, don't appears anything at all.

Comment: @Valter: then you're not using it correctly. http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/introduction-to-firebug-net-panel/

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use the root as a reference?

`<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Comment: Maybe his site isn't getting deployed to the root of a domain? foo.com/bar/hisSite/

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your path from the root URL to make this easier, with the '/' at the front.

```
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need two `../`.

Try this:

```
<link href="../../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../css/inner.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: I don't think so. First ../ brings him to 2011. Second ../ brings him to blog. Third ../ brings him to root.

Comment: @Steve: Right, I misinterpreted his screenshot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just do this to get to your web root:

```
<link href="/css/style.css">
```

Rather than fiddling with relative paths, go absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Your paths look OK, are you sure the CSS files were uploaded to your server and that the file names are actually correct?

In doubt with ".." navigation, move your files closer and do some trials and error until you get it.